# Linq how to use an OR?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can someone show me how to do an OR on a LinQ statement? For example if I have two extension methods: `ByIdA()` and `ByIdB()`. Then I want to use them similar to:

```
var yada = _something.Entity.ByIdA().ByIdB();
```

The above will call both and return rows where A and B are both true. How can I write it to use OR and returns rows where A or B are true?

I have an entity A with an Icollection of child table B, so I want to return rows from A where either A.x = 1 or B.y = 1.

Comment: `Predicate Builder` class can help you. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a single where

```
_collection.Where(x => x.ByIdA() || x.ByIdB());
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in this example, `ByIdA` and `ByIdB` are extension methods attached to `IEnumerable<T>`, not `T`, so you'd need separate methods to handle an individual item instead of a collection of items.

Comment: True, I wasn't quite sure what he was getting at with `_something.Entity`. A little confusing.

Answer (score 6):

To return the union of two collections, you can use the [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) operator.

```
_something.Entity.ByIdA().Union(_something.Entity.ByIdB())
```

If your collections don't have any common elements, you can use the [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) operator, which is cheaper since it does not check for duplicates.

Comment: It is also important if any of the two sequences has duplicate elements in itself, of course.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ probably isn't the way to solve this one. Each LINQ method acts independently, so if you managed to get your OR in a chain like this, it would difficult to read, and definitely difficult to understand and debug.

You probably just want to OR the old fashioned way:

```
_something.Entity.Where(x => IsA(x) || IsB(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question could use:

```
var list = _something.Entity;
var result = Enumerable.Union(list.ByIdA(), list.ByIdB());
```

But for the second part, which seems another question, There's need to clarify the question. If you mean that each of A objects has a list of B(s) and You want all A objects which `A.x==1` or `A.Bs.Any(b=>b.y==1)` then you could use:

```
var result = list.Where(a => a.x==1 || a=>a.Bs.Any(b=>b.y==1));
```